# How can I watch a variable in Ruby Pry?

Tags: ruby, debugging, pry, byebug

I'm using Ruby 2.2.2, Pry and 'pry-byebug'. The `continue` statement removes any watched variables in have in `pry-byebug`:

```
[1] pry(main)> watch foo
Watching foo
watch: foo => 42
[2] pry(main)> watch
Listing all watched expressions:

1: foo => 42

[3] pry(main)> continue
[1] pry(main)> watch
No watched expressions
```

Losing them on every `continue` makes watched expressions pretty worthless. If I use `next` and step to the same point in the code instead, the watched expressions are still there; it's just the `continue` that causes the problem. At the moment I can't even find any documentation on the `watch` statement, so I don't know why this occurs.

More generally, I just want to print out the value of a set of expressions on every Pry prompt (or, perhaps, print them out if they've changed since the last time they were printed.) How can I achieve this in a Ruby debugger?

Comment: The integration of byebug into pry is quite a hack. They don't often play well together. Haven't used watch before so alas cannot help with this one. Maybe just email the author of byebug?

Answer (score 2):

Using [pry-moves](https://github.com/garmoshka-mo/pry-moves) you can use `watch variable` - this will display value of variable on each step.

Comment: Haven't had a chance to try this yet but it looks like what i want.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to write a plugin that just shows the expressions after evaluating if that's  *exactly* what you want. 
[Pry plugins](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Hooks#Hooks_after_eval_event)

Which you could do something simple like

```
Pry.hooks.add_hook(:after_eval, "reporter") do |output, binding, pry|
  $watch ||= [] 
  $watch.each {|block| block.call} 
end

$watch = [-> { puts "hello"}]
```

Or something along the lines of that, would report "hello" after each new evaluation. (this is untested however, currently on mobile)